# Media Queries are overriding

Tags: css, reactjs, media-queries

I have two media queries, one targeting max-width: 991px and the other for 1300px. I want to implement different styles for my `.image-div`. However, when I implement the styles in the media query of max-width: 991px, it doesn't work. But if I implement the same style in the 1300px max-width, it gets implemented in the 1300px and also in the 991px. I don't know why it is so.

```css
@media (max-width: 991px) {
  .Trends {
    color: black;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    gap: 2rem;
    width: 35.3rem;
    min-width: 34.5rem;
    margin-top: -113rem;
    position: absolute;
  }
  .text {
    background-color: red;
    opacity: 100;
  }
  .trend-head {
    margin-top: 22rem;
    padding: 0.7rem;
    margin-left: -14rem;
  }
  .trend-input {
    width: 12rem;
    margin-right: 0rem;
    font-size: 15px;
  }
  .dr-arrow {
    background-color: rgb(201, 195, 195);
    font-size: 35px;
    padding: 0.7rem;
    margin-right: rem;
    margin-top: 1.1rem;
  }
  .input-arrow {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: center;
    margin-top: 21rem;
    margin-right: 22rem;
  }
  .Array-list {
    margin-left: 0.5rem;
    color: gray;
    line-height: 5px;
  }
  .Array-div ul {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    float: right;
    justify-content: space-between;
    list-style: none;
  }
  .Array-list:hover {
    color: orangered;
  }
  .Array-div {
    margin-top: 17rem;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: rgb(245, 244, 244);
    padding: 1rem 8rem 1rem 1rem;
    border: 1px light black;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    border-top: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    z-index: 1;
  }
  .red {
    color: red;
  }
  .image-container {
    position: relative;
  }
  .image-container img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 0.9s ease;
  }
  .image-container img:nth-child(1) {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  .image-container:hover img:nth-child(2) {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  .image-div {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    margin-top: 0rem;
  }
  .image-div-first-img {
    width: 16rem;
  }
  .image-div-second-img {
    width: 16rem;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 1300px) {
  .Trends {
    color: black;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    gap: 2rem;
    width: 55rem;
    min-width: 34.5rem;
    margin-top: -145rem;
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: 21rem;
  }
  .trend-head {
    margin-left: 1rem;
    background-color: rgb(21, 9, 55);
    color: white;
    padding: 0.7rem 1.5rem;
  }
  /* .Array-list-vertical {
        display: block;
        color: black;
        margin-left: 0.5rem;
        color: gray; 
    } */
  /* .Array-list-horizontal {
        display: flex;
        list-style-type: none;
        padding: 0;
    }  */
  .Array-list {
    color: gray;
  }
  .Array-list:hover {
    color: orangered;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  .input-arrow {
    /* flex-direction: row;
        align-items: center;
        margin-top: -19rem;
        margin-right: -20rem; */
  }
  .Array-div ul {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    float: right;
    justify-content: space-between;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    gap: 1rem;
  }
  .red {
    color: red;
  }
  .image-container {
    position: relative;
    /* Adjust height as needed */
  }
  .image-container img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: -7.5rem;
    width: 10rem;
    height: 10rem;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 0.9s ease;
  }
  .image-container img:nth-child(1) {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  .image-container:hover img:nth-child(2) {
    opacity: 1;
    /* Second image becomes visible on hover */
  }
  .image-div {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    width: 50rem;
    height: 35rem;
    justify-content: space-between;
    margin-top: -145%;
    margin-right: 5rem;
    float: right;
  }
  .image-div-first-img {
    width: 16rem;
  }
  .image-div-second-img {
    width: 16rem;
  }
}
```

Comment: if a screen is 600px wide, then the condition `max-width: 991` and `max-width: 1300px` are both true and the last will overwrite the one before. Try using `min-width` instead! or limit by adding a minimum condition such as `@media only screen and (min-width: 992px) and (max-width: 1300px)`

Comment: Remember the C in CSS. The setting that comes last, if it has the same weight, wins. (Cascading). Put the smaller max-width media settings after ypthe other one.